# Proof that existsts $\delta>0$ such that $2-\frac{1}{3} < x^2 +x < 2+\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that exists:

$\delta>0$ such that $1-\delta < x < 1+ \delta\implies 2-\frac{1}{3} < x^2 +x < 2+\frac{1}{3}$

What I did:

$1-\delta < x < 1+ \delta\implies |x-1|<\delta$ and then I suppose that:

$$|x+2|<\delta$$

So:

$$|x-1||x+2|<\delta^2$$

And then I have:

$$|x^2 +x -2|<\delta^2$$

By setting: $\delta^2 = \frac{1}{3}$ we have $\delta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ then:
$$|x^2 +x -2|<\frac{1}{3} \tag{for $\delta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$}$$

But then I graphed this and it didn't work. How, then, it could be done? Where's my error? Is it in supposing $|x+2|<\delta$ too?

Comment: Yes, assuming $|x+2|\lt \delta$ is not right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why? What could I do, then? Thank you, so much :)

Comment: I have written out a solution. Note that the $\delta$ I found, namely $\frac{1}{12}$, is by no means the largest $\delta$ that will work. By fooling around with the quadratic, we could, *in this case*, find an explicit expression for the largest $\delta$ that will ensure the inequality $2-1/3\lt x^2+x\lt 2+1/3$ holds. However, the point of this exercise is to find *some* $\delta$ that works, and to have a tight proof that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We continue on the path you started. We want $|x-1||x+2|$ to be "small." The idea is to make $|x-1|$ small, that is, to choose $x$ close to $1$.

Unfortunately, the $x+2$ term could spoil things. But for example if we make $|x-1|\lt \frac{1}{2}$, then $x+2$ will be between $2+\frac{1}{2}$ and $2+\frac{3}{2}$, and in particular will be positive and less than $4$. So if we make $|x-1|\lt \frac{1}{12}$, then $|x-1||x+2|$ will be less than $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: How did you transform $2 + \frac{1}{2}$ and $2+\frac{3}{2}$ back in the modulus form so you knew the product $|x-1||x+2|$ would be less than $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Hmm, I understood what you did. You know that when $|x-1|<\frac{1}{2}$, then $|x+2|<4$. You can, then, set $|x-1|<\frac{1}{12}<\frac{1}{2}$ then the product of the two ones will be $\frac{1}{12}\cdot 4 = \frac{1}{3}$ right? Is there a more precise way to solve this that will work without 'trying' values? Thank you sooooo much c:

Comment: So you have no trouble seeing that if we make sure that $|x-1|\lt 1/2$, then $x+2$ is between $2.5$ and $3.5$. In particular, it is positive and less than $4$, so it has absolute value less than $4$.

Comment: In this kind of problem, it is best to decide, on the basis of informal "geometric" reasoning, what might work, and then **verify formally** that it does work.

Comment: Thank you so much, André! <3

Comment: You are welcome. This concrete numerical problem is preparation for more abstract problems in which the same issue comes up. For example, you will have an expression $|x-a||g(x)|$ that you want to make $\lt \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is an unspecified positive number (in your problem it is $1/3$). You will want to show that there is a $\delta$ such that if $|x-a|\lt \delta$, your expression is $\lt \epsilon$. The trick will be getting control over the size of $|g(x)|$.